# Java Text file parsing error

Tags: java

If the file has a blank line as the last line of the file, it blows out after the while statement.  Can someone help?

```
while(in.hasNext())
{
   tempPropID = in.nextInt();
   tempPropType = in.next().toUpperCase();
   tempPropCost =  in.nextDouble();
   tempAgentID = in.nextByte(WIDTH);
}
```

Comment: And what is after while?

Comment: @where exactly after while?, have your tried debugging your code. what exact line blows out?

Comment: Please provide a bit more info, like the input file, expected output, and the error.

Comment: Please add more codes and file content you tried!

Answer (score 4):

When this code is responsible for the error you should try analyze the methods you are using.
For example the `in.next().toUppercase()` is vulnerable to throw a `NullPointerException`.